# sql queries with and without aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, having-clause, relational-division

I have 4 tables created like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
    ssn CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(32),
    last_name VARCHAR(32),
    country VARCHAR(16)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS credit_cards (
    ssn CHAR(11) REFERENCES customers(ssn), 
    number VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
    type VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS merchants (
    code CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    country VARCHAR(16)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(
    identifier INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
    number VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES credit_cards(number),  
    code CHAR(10) REFERENCES merchants(code),  
    datetime TIMESTAMP,  
    amount NUMERIC
);
```

And I want to find the codes and the names of the different merchants who did not entertain transactions for every type of credit card. I was wondering one way to do it with aggregate and one way without aggregate.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I understand this as a relational division problem. You want merchants that do not have transactions for every possible credit card types.

One option is aggregation and filtering with a having clause:

```
select m.*
from merchants m
inner join transactions t on t.code = m.code
inner join credit_cards cc on cc.number = m.number
group by m.code
having count(distinct cc.type) < (select count(distinct type) from credit_cards)
```